# How to test multiple images at once with label_image.py in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have been researching a way to load my  multi classification tensorflow module with 25-30 scans of images at once. It currently only runs one image at a time in the test stage. The idea is to compare them all at once through an editted label_image.py and ran in docker through tensorflow library. I have had hopes to figure this out myself but to no avail. I am currently under the assumption that although it is possible to test multiple images at once, I am unsure as to where I should edit in labe_image.py. My thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem with me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop after

```
graph = load_graph(model_file)
files=["tf_files/1.jpg","tf_files/2.jpg"]
```

like this:

```
for file_name in files:
  t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,input_height=input_height,input_std=input_std)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!